# What are laplace and fourier transformations used for practically?

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Currently, we are studying Laplace and Fourier Series and I have learned the method but it's just too abstract for me.

All practical info we were given for Laplace is that it transforms one function to another and so you can do something with that new function (that you couldn't with the original one) and reverse it back.

Similar information for Fourier series.

I would also highly appreciate if someone answers as deeply as possible this question or even better yet points me to some book that explains these topics.

I am not interested in the proof or any high level math.

I see them as tools and I would like to know what are they best suited for so I can spot the application. I am pursuing a BSc in ComputerScience so DSP is kinda not so familiar to me. But nicely explained DSP applications are also cool.

Comment: differential equation, convolution, filtering, pitch  $f_0$ and periodicity extraction, trigonometric series / representation, interpolation, sampling, smoothness and decrease at $\infty$, analyticity.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes but you just did what my teachers do. You will need it in the future for x, y, z. Maybe it would be better to say okay we have this kind of real-world problem. It is solved by filtering/convolution/diff equations. This is diff equation/convolution/filtering and these are the parameters we are working with, in it. We can solve it with this tool called Laplace transformation and it works like this.

Comment: this is way too broad. tell us more on your level and a problem that is interesting to you

Comment: @user1952009 I like your response! I am most interested in machine learning domain but I always find things interesting when they are well explained. Especially engineering stuff. I don't have a strong math background, just calculus, probability and statistics, and a bit of 3d functions.

Comment: There are thousands of Fourier transform in your everyday life. In your cellphone for compressing the image to compression of your voice is based on Fourier. When you use DSL, or Wifi, it is based on Fourier Transform. So it is one of the most practical algorithms.

Comment: Also useful to transform a mathematical problem to different "space" (where it is much easier - or faster, or cheaper - to resolve) and then send back to primary "space". @msm already recorded some specific examples.

Comment: @msm Yeah. I get that. But that is like really a high-level explanation. There is no way I can relate what I have learned to compressing image or voice :/

Comment: electrical circuits are based on (linear) differential operators : resistance, inductance, capacitor are much simpler in the Fourier frequency domain. the non linear elements : DC/AC supply, transistor (and RLC in limit cases) are more complicated, but can still be understood in term of non linear operator acting in the frequency domain. In the same way, any digital sound processing algorithm can be understood as acting in the frequency domain. In other words : without the Fourier/Laplace transform you understand nothing.

Comment: [Using Google, one can find this.](https://www.quora.com/What-practical-uses-does-the-Laplace-transform-have)

Comment: @z100 Nice point. I like the "much cheaper" part. Any more a bit in depth stuff?

Comment: Try "Fourier transform and PDE" or for a discrete case aplicable in computing science "Fast Fourier transform" there is a nice article on Wikipedia.

Comment: Using Google, one can also find [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69/why-is-the-fourier-transform-so-important) and [that](http://www.askamathematician.com/2012/09/q-what-is-a-fourier-transform-what-is-it-used-for/).

Comment: A mathematician once solved a mystery about the Beatle's song "A Hard Day's Night" using Fourier analysis.  https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/10/081030201607.htm